# Angular 2 Components and bootstrap css grid placement

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm using angular 2 to create a page using different components. My layout is kinda like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <x-header></x-header>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <x-sidebar></x-sidebar>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <x-table></x-table>
        </div>
    `,
    directives: [HeaderComponent, SidebarComponent, TableComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

that is my main component that gets loaded from the index.html - the other components contain the tags and css pertaining to their parts. I'm adding bootstrap.min.css in the index.html and I wanted the grid system to be applied to the whole page, so I could have the components fit together. Yet, this is the layout of the current page.

[image: the screenshot]
As you can see the table is being rendered from the start of the page, and it goes under the sidebar and the header. I'm not sure if it's important, but I plan to add a "toggle nav bar" button somewhere.

EDIT: My question is, why are the components fitting in together? Why is the table underneath the header and sidebar? Why isn't the bootstrap grid system working?

Comment: Forgot to ask question.

Comment: @Jai ops.. sorry.. yeah, but like the image suggests... why is that happening?

Answer (score 2):

This seems more of a css issue.

Bootstrap grid system works like count of 12 meaning if you have two elements on the page in a block then if first element is `col-md-4` then second should be `col-md-8` to fit in horizontally.

[@Bootstrap grid system.](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

In your case it might be possible at template:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <x-header></x-header>
        <div class="col-md-3"><!-- change to col-md-3 -->
            <x-sidebar></x-sidebar>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9"><!-- change to col-md-9 -->
            <x-table></x-table>
        </div>
    `,
    directives: [HeaderComponent, SidebarComponent, TableComponent]
})
```

For header you have to inspect if that element is statically positioned.

Comment: the css doesnt seem to be applying properly, I tried to wrap all the tags in the same div so all the content occupies 1 single column (ridiculous but just to prove my point). Yet nothing happened... the page layout is the same as if I had no divs. Is angular changing the way bootstrap grid system works?

Comment: Well can't say anything about it but angular2 is messing the design i don't think so. but a demo would be great if possible can you create such issue here: http://plnkr.co/edit

Comment: I just discovered the issue. The designer wrote some custom css for the sidebar that forced that position and the table was coping with it. I'm getting different results with the default bootstrap library (I was using a customized one)

Comment: @Thaenor That is what i mentioned at first line. Glad you got it resolved finally.

Comment: kinda... now I need to rewrite the css... Thanks for helping me figure this out :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the parent div with class "row", change the code to this:

`` @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <x-header></x-header>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <x-sidebar></x-sidebar>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <x-table></x-table>
                </div>
        </div>
    `,
    directives: [HeaderComponent, SidebarComponent, TableComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {} ``